# langchain SQLDatabaseChain can't find the table in an in-memory sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, langchain

In python, I have an sqlite3 in-memory database:

```
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
```

I've populated it with a simple table and some data from a pandas dataframe.

I know the table exists; it shows when I do
`cur.execute("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master where type='table';")`

and I get `my_table` back.

I've already set up an llm as well.

Now, I'd like to pass it into a langchain `SQLDatabaseChain` as such:

```
from langchain_community.utilities import SQLDatabase
db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm, db)
```

So I do:

```
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(
            "sqlite:///:memory:"
             schema="main",
             include_tables=["mytable"],
```

but the table doesn't show up:

```
File "/home/me/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_community/utilities/sql_database.py", line 73, in __init__raise ValueError(
ValueError: include_tables {'mytable'} not found in database
```

How can I make `SQLDatabaseChain` find the table in an in-memory sqlite database?